# What is the correct syntax to use with MSTest.exe to run an .orderedtest file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, ordered-test

In a VS2015 Unit Test project you are able to right click the project and add an ordered test. This enables you to order your unit tests in a file with the extension orderedtest.

I can't find the correct syntax to use with MSTest.exe to run this orderedtest file.

Comment: Why would you order tests? Sound as not very good idea, tests should be independent.

Comment: The tests are independent. The feature exists and I'd like to know how to use it. What I'm testing isn't a production piece of software but a tutorial for learning purposes. :-)

Comment: Do you have enterprise edition, seems that only enterprise edition has this feature?

Comment: Using professional, and I've added an orderedtest with no issues at all. Also runs using the IDE. I just require the correct MSTest syntax. I can run tests using MSTest but can't run the orderedtest file. I'm certain it must be able to and the issue is syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test container is a file that contains the tests you want to run. For example, for ordered tests, the test container is the .orderedtest file that defines the ordered test. For unit tests, it is the assembly built from the test project that contains the unit test source files.

```
MSTest /TestContainer:OrderedTest1.orderedtest
```

**See Also**
[How to run a ordered test from MSTest command line](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16d4f71c-126a-4408-ab32-5f3d027c0ab5/how-to-run-a-ordered-test-from-mstest-command-line?forum=vststest)

Comment: Thank you. I thought the test container still had to point to the dll and there was another switch for the test file. Nice to know where I'm going wrong. Happy Holidays.